# Can I restrict access to Cloud Storage only to instances running on cloud run?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

We have a few front and back end services running on Cloud Run. In Cloud Storage we store things such as files and images.

What I want to achieve is accessing the images from my front-end Cloud Run instances and only from my front-end Cloud Run instances. The images by default should, if accessed from other services, throw a 401.

Do you have any suggestions? For now we are not able to figure out a way of doing so.

Comment: It depends how work your frontend service. Can  you describe it more? Do you serve the content dynamically (server side rendering) or does it serve static file (browser side rendering, with JS as any modern web framework)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are generating the pages server side with Next.js. The user is authenticated using a different authentication method than Google Cloud related ones (Auth0 or Firebase). The files served are dynamically added to Cloud Storage by other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page are generated by your frontend service, you can restrict the access to the file to only the Cloud Run frontend service.

For that, you have to deploy your service with [a custom service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity).

Then, go to your bucket and remove all the permissions on it, and add only the Cloud Run custom [service account the permissions to access the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control). Use uniform access control on your bucket.

Like that, only the frontend service account will be allowed to access to the bucket.